# How are CPU instruction dependency graphs built?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

We talk a lot about out of order and superscalar processors having optimisations viable only after we verify that some instructions do not depend on one another.

How are these dependency graphs built by our processor (e.g. what algorithm)? When are they built? If they are built early on, how and where do we store this information on the CPU?

Comment: The construction of dependency graphs is a continuous process that happens as instructions are fetched and decoded. The information is stored in the processor's internal data structures, which are optimized for the speed and complexity of modern instruction streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its built on the fly as instructions/uops are moved from the in-order front-end (where uops use architectural register numbers) into the out-of-order back-end (where uops use physical register numbers for their input and output operands).  "architectural register number" is the 3 to 5-bit field in the machine code that identifies a register, e.g. `000` for x86's AL/AX/EAX/RAX. x86 high-8 [partial registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) like AH complicate this but we'll ignore them; most ISAs don't have that problem.

The RAT (Register Allocation Table) is the key structure for out-of-order exec CPUs to find out which previous outputs an instruction/uop is reading. Each write of a register is allocated a physical register, and updates the RAT's mapping of architectural to physical.  **Every read of an architectural register gets the current physical-register number for that architectural register from the RAT.  This is an edge in the dependency graph, from this reader to the writer that produced this output.**

The scheduler aka Reservation Station (RS) then tracks when inputs are ready in terms of physical registers.

Values that were written long ago by instructions that have long since retired are still in a physical register file (PRF) entry, with the RAT pointing to it.  Some number of PRF entries are basically used up holding the architectural state.  (See https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/ which mentions this, and how PRF size can be the limiting factor for out-of-order exec window if most of the instructions write a register.  Branches and stores don't, loads and ALU instructions do.)

Instructions (or uops in CPUs like modern x86 that decodes complex instructions to multiple micro-ops) are processed in groups of 3 to 6 per clock cycle depending on how wide the pipeline is.  The allocate/rename stage is the first part of detecting dependencies, as they're copied from the in-order front-end to the out-of-order back-end of the core.  Intel calls this "issue", most of the rest of the computer-architecture world calls this "dispatch".  (And the opposite terms is used by Intel vs. everyone else to describe sending a uop to an execution unit.)

And yes, in typical CPUs, the RAT can rename the same register multiple times in a clock cycle.  For example in x86, FLAGS is written by most scalar ALU instructions so this is necessary, but it's also possible for other registers.  A chain of computations RMWing the same register like RISC-V `add x1, x1, x3` ; `add x1, x1, x3` ; ... is also not rare.  They can't *execute* in parallel because of the dependencies, but we don't want to stall alloc/rename as well, that would defeat the purpose of out-of-order exec to see what independent work might be past it.  So the ability to rename the same register multiple times in a clock cycle is AFAIK widespread; compilers don't need to cycle through different architectural registers for different temporaries in the same chain.  (GCC sometimes does that, but I don't think it helps on any out-of-order CPUs, and probably not in-order either.)

Typically x86 CPUs have PRF (physical register file) entries that can hold both an integer and a FLAGS result, so the RAT entries for RAX and FLAGS could both point to the same PRF entry until one or the other of those architectural registers is overwritten.  So instructions like `add eax, ecx` can be treated as having only one physical-register output, even though readers might depend on it different ways (like `cmovc edx, ebx` reading FLAGS and `lea edi, [rax+1]` reading the integer reg.)

---

So far so simple, the RAT has the current mapping from architectural to physical, and each uop reads and possibly updates that.

With some clever logic, that can be done multiple times per cycle.  The difficulty of this scales maybe quadratically with pipeline width, so it's hard to make really wide pipelines.  And it costs significant power.

The other hard part is the need to roll back to a previous state on any mis-speculation, such as a mispredicted branch, or an instruction that faulted like a bad address or divide by zero.  This needs to roll the RAT back to a previous snapshot, and free physical registers allocated for uops being discarded (either now or after they finish, if the CPU is unable to abort something like a division in progress that will produce an output much later).  I'm not sure if this rollback usually involves scanning through the intervening instructions, between the state we're rolling back to and the current dispatch (Intel "issue") position.  The ROB (ReOrder Buffer) does have all those uops in program order, whether they've executed and left the scheduler or not, so that would be possible.

---

Related:

- https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/5/ - David Kanter's write up of Sandybridge (and his later Haswell writeup) are very good.  SnB was Intel's first since Pentium 4 to use a PRF.  (P6 family kept in-flight results in the ROB itself, with architectural state in a separate "retirement register file".)
- [Modern Microprocessors
  A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) - very good background on the whole subject, although doesn't get into the terminology of RAT / ROB / PRF for the parts that CPUs use to find parallelism.  Still highly worth a read to cover the basics of what CPUs are trying to do, and the big picture of some tradeoffs they have to make.  (IPC vs. clock frequency vs. power).